# Documentation on patch attributes

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm trying to patch an attribute from a class, and after a lot of searching in SO I understood that only class attributes "can" be patched. If I want to patch object attributes I have to "create" them (use the `create=True` option in patch).

Example:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self._a = 5

class B(A):

    def ok(self):
        a = A()
        print(a._a)

def test(mocker):
    mocker.patch("test_scratch.A._a", return_value=3)
```

This example uses pytest-mock.

Running this with `pytest`, in a file called `test_scratch.py` results in the following error:

> AttributeError: <class 'test_scratch.A'> does not have the attribute '_a'

I understand why this is, but after reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) I can't find this explained anywhere. Which makes me wounder how much more I'm missing (i.e., how many more relevant details I'm flying over).

So, where is this behavior documented?

Comment: `_a` is an instance attribute, so you need an instance of `A` to patch. The problem is that your only reference to the instance is a local variable, which isn't something you can reference to patch.  You would essentially need to patch `test_scratch.A.__init__` with a function that defines the attribute for you. The fact that this is troublesome suggests that your code needs to be refactored. (Sometimes, the difficulty in writing a test in the first place uncovers bugs just as well as a failed test.)

Comment: For example, perhaps `B.ok` should take an instance of `A` as an argument, rather than creating one itself.

Comment: I understand the problem. But only a lot of research in SO. My question is if this is clear from the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is clearly document in the first paragraph.

> Inside the body of the function or with statement, the target is patched with a new object.

From this sentence I understand `patch` will set an object inside an already existing reference.
You are trying to place a specific value into a variable that does not exist.